# How to debug audio cards (missing recording channels)

Tags: audio, alsa, usb-audio

I have a StudioLive AR8 USB mixer by PreSonus that also functions as an audio card. What is so neat about this is that I get 2 playback channels and 4 recording channels! (1× stereo playback, 2× stereo capture) — However, since some time ago I one disappeared. Now I want to get to the bottom of this. PreSonus doesn't offer Linux support, so I cannot ask them. But it worked out of the box before! So there must be a way to find how to get it back.

Please teach me what I need to do. I suspect somewhere it doesn't detect the extra channels anymore.

I am currently running Arch with the `5.4.98-1-lts` kernel, and am also using PipeWire.

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card1/stream0 
PreSonus StudioLive AR8 at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, full speed : USB Audio

Playback:
  Status: Running
    Interface = 1
    Altset = 1
    Packet Size = 294
    Momentary freq = 47994 Hz (0x2f.fe80)
    Feedback Format = 18.14
  Interface 1
    Altset 1
    Format: S24_3LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 1 OUT (ASYNC)
    Rates: 44100, 48000
    Bits: 24
  Interface 1
    Altset 2
    Format: S16_LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 1 OUT (ASYNC)
    Rates: 44100, 48000
    Bits: 16
  Interface 1
    Altset 3
    Format: SPECIAL
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 1 OUT (ASYNC)
    Rates: 44100, 48000
    Bits: 32

Capture:
  Status: Running
    Interface = 2
    Altset = 1
    Packet Size = 294
    Momentary freq = 48000 Hz (0x30.0000)
  Interface 2
    Altset 1
    Format: S24_3LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 2 IN (ASYNC)
    Rates: 44100, 48000
    Bits: 24
```

dmesg when plugging it in: (maybe that unsupported format bits is a hint?)

```
[712103.555521] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 42 using xhci_hcd
[712103.745829] usb 1-1: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[712103.747418] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=194f, idProduct=0703, bcdDevice= 1.14
[712103.747423] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=0
[712103.747426] usb 1-1: Product: StudioLive AR8
[712103.747429] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: PreSonus
[712103.764747] usb 1-1: 1:3 : unsupported format bits 0x100000000
```